Can a list comprehension that builds a list of lists referring to itself be done in one line?
I have a number of list comprehensions that build a variety of lists of lists. To keep this simple, consider:
foo = []
for i in range(1,3):  # dummy loop for the example
    if len(foo) == 0:
        foo = [[x] for x in (0, 1, -1)]  # can I avoid this step?
    else:
        foo = [f + [x] for f in foo for x in (0, 1, -1)]
print(foo)

produces:
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]]

I know there are other ways using itertools to produce this particular output; I'm simplifying here. The key is that the comprehension has to build on itself, therefore the for f in foo.
My specific question is: is there a way to avoid the if, else code and just do this in one line?
If I just do foo = [f + [x] for f in foo for x in (0, 1, -1)] without the case for len(foo) == 0 I get an empty foo.

1- 1-liners just for the sake of it is rarely a good idea. 2- why not just put the initialization in the first line?  foo = [[x] for x in (0, 1, -1)] then for i in range(2,3): foo = [f + [x] for f in foo for x in (0, 1, -1)]

No, there's no way to refer to the list being constructed until it's done.

You could use a recursive function for this.

@julien re 2. because the real loop is iterating over another structure and there's more logic before the len(foo) test . I'd have to write my outer loop twice in order to find the first case where foo can get started.

Not clear. However complicated it is, it's run only once at the start of the outer loop, so just take it out of the outer loop...

@Barmar A way.

You need to initialise the foo as an empty two-dimension list so that you that you can get the correct result without adding len(foo) == 0.
Here is the complete code:
foo = [[]]
for i in range(1, 3):
    foo = [f + [x] for f in foo for x in (0, 1, -1)]
print(foo)

Then the result:
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, -1], [-1, 0], [-1, 1], [-1, -1]]


Wow! I thought at first this would only work for my dummy loop case, but no, it works for any size loop. I knew there would be some smarty out there with a solution. Very nice.
